# workflow for creating timevarying covariates in r

Tags: r, workflow, survival-analysis

I have a huge data file in long format-parts of it supplied below. Each ID can have several rows, where status is the final status. However I need to do the analysis with time varying covariates and hence need to create two new time variables and update the status variable. I´ve been struggling with this for some time now and I cannot figure out how to do this efficiently as there can be as many as four rows per ID. The time varying variable is `NUM.AFTER.DIAG`. If `NUM.AFTER.DIAG==0` then it is easy, where `time1=0` and `time2=STATUSDATE`. However when `NUM.AFTER.DIAG==1` then I need to make a new row where `time1=0`, `time2=DOB-DATE.DIAG` and `NUM.AFTER.DIAG=0` and also make sure `STATUS="B"`. The second row would then be `time1=time2` from the previous row and `time2=STATUSDATE-DATE.DIAG-time1` from this row. Equally if there are more rows then the different rows needs to be subtracted from each other. Also if NUM.AFTER.DIAG==0 but there are multiple rows then all extra rows can be deleted.

Any ideas for an efficient solution to this?
 I´ve looked at john Fox unfold command, but it assumes that all the intervals are in wide format to begin with.

Edit: The table as requested. As for the censor variable: "D"=event (death)

[image]

```
 structure(list(ID = c(187L, 258L, 265L, 278L, 281L, 281L, 283L, 
    283L, 284L, 291L, 292L, 292L, 297L, 299L, 305L, 305L, 311L, 311L, 
    319L, 319L, 319L, 322L, 322L, 329L, 329L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 334L, 
    334L), STATUS = c("D", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "D", "D", "B", 
    "B", "B", "B", "D", "D", "D", "D", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "D", 
    "D", "B", "B", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D"), STATUSDATE = structure(c(11153, 
    15034, 15034, 15034, 15034, 15034, 5005, 5005, 15034, 15034, 
    15034, 15034, 6374, 5005, 7562, 7562, 15034, 15034, 15034, 15034, 
    15034, 7743, 7743, 15034, 15034, 4670, 4670, 4670, 5218, 5218
    ), class = "Date"), DATE.DIAG = structure(c(4578, 4609, 4578, 
    4487, 4670, 4670, 4517, 4517, 4640, 4213, 4397, 4397, 4397, 4487, 
    4213, 4213, 4731, 4731, 4701, 4701, 4701, 4397, 4397, 4578, 4578, 
    4275, 4275, 4275, 4456, 4456), class = "Date"), DOB = structure(c(NA, 
    13010, NA, NA, -1082, -626, 73, 1353, 13679, NA, 1626, 3087, 
    -626, -200, 2814, 3757, 1930, 3787, 6740, 13528, 14167, 5462, 
    6557, 7865, 9235, -901, -504, -108, -535, -78), class = "Date"), 
        NUM.AFTER.DIAG = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("ID", 
    "STATUS", "STATUSDATE", "DATE.DIAG", "DOB", "NUM.AFTER.DIAG"), row.names = c(NA, 
    30L), class = "data.frame")
```

EDIT: I did come up with a solution, although probably not very efficient.

```
  u1<-ddply(p,.(ID),function(x) {

  if (x$NUM.AFTER.DIAG==0){

    x$time1<-0
    x$time2<-x$STATUSDATE-x$DATE.DIAG
    x<-x[1,]

  }
  else {

      x<-rbind(x,x[1,])
      x<-x[order(x$DOB),]
      u<-max(x$NUM.AFTER.DIAG)
      x$NUM.AFTER.DIAG<-0:u
      x$time1[1]<-0
      x$time2[1:(u)]<-x$DOB[2:(u+1)]-x$DATE.DIAG[2:(u+1)]
      x$time2[u+1]<-x$STATUSDATE[u]-x$DATE.DIAG[u]
      x$time1[2:(u+1)]<-x$time2[1:u]
      x$STATUS[1:u]<-"B"
      }
  x
}
)
```

Comment: could you provide an example (in form of a table) of how your data is supposed to look like after transformation, let's say for IDs 258, 299, 319 and 333? What is your `STATUS` variable indicating? `B` = event, `D`= censoring?

Comment: do you already have a solution and want to make it more efficient or do you know how to do it for each individual separately, but struggle to apply it to all individuals? - thanks for the EDIT btw

Comment: I did find a solution just now using plyr and rbind in order to add the extra columns needed... I´ll add it and leave it up for someone to find a more efficient way..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've tried something, but I'm not sure I understand your transformation process entirely, so let me know if there are some mistakes. In general `ddply` will be slow (even when `.parallel = TRUE`), when there are many individuals, mainly because at the end it has to bring all the data sets of all individuals together and `rbind` (or `rbind.fill`) them, which takes forever for a multitude of `data.frame` objects.

So here's a suggestion, where `dat.orig` is your toy data set:

I would first split the task in two:
1)  `NUM.AFTER.DIAG == 0`
2) `NUM.AFTER.DIAG == 1`

1) It seems that if `NUM.AFTER.DIAG == 0`, except of calculating time2 and extract first row if an ID occurs more than once (like ID 333), there is not much to do in part 1):

```
## erase multiple occurences
dat <- dat.orig[!(duplicated(dat.orig$ID) & dat.orig$NUM.AFTER.DIAG == 0), ]
dat0 <- dat[dat$NUM.AFTER.DIAG == 0, ]
dat0$time1 <- 0
dat0$time2 <- difftime(dat0$STATUSDATE, dat0$DATE.DIAG, unit = "days")
time.na <- is.na(dat0$DOB)
dat0$time1[time.na] <- dat0$time2[time.na] <- NA

> dat0
    ID STATUS STATUSDATE  DATE.DIAG        DOB NUM.AFTER.DIAG time1      time2
1  187      D 2000-07-15 1982-07-15       <NA>              0    NA    NA days
3  265      B 2011-03-01 1982-07-15       <NA>              0    NA    NA days
4  278      B 2011-03-01 1982-04-15       <NA>              0    NA    NA days
5  281      B 2011-03-01 1982-10-15 1967-01-15              0     0 10364 days
7  283      D 1983-09-15 1982-05-15 1970-03-15              0     0   488 days
10 291      B 2011-03-01 1981-07-15       <NA>              0    NA    NA days
11 292      B 2011-03-01 1982-01-15 1974-06-15              0     0 10637 days
13 297      D 1987-06-15 1982-01-15 1968-04-15              0     0  1977 days
14 299      D 1983-09-15 1982-04-15 1969-06-15              0     0   518 days
15 305      D 1990-09-15 1981-07-15 1977-09-15              0     0  3349 days
17 311      B 2011-03-01 1982-12-15 1975-04-15              0     0 10303 days
26 333      D 1982-10-15 1981-09-15 1967-07-15              0     0   395 days
29 334      D 1984-04-15 1982-03-15 1968-07-15              0     0   762 days
```

2) is a little trickier, but all you actually have to do is insert one more row and calculate the time variables:

```
## create subset with relevant observations
dat.unfold <- dat[dat$NUM.AFTER.DIAG != 0, ]
## compute time differences
time1 <- difftime(dat.unfold$DOB, dat.unfold$DATE.DIAG, unit = "days")
time1[time1 < 0] <- 0
time2 <- difftime(dat.unfold$STATUSDATE, dat.unfold$DATE.DIAG, unit = "days")

## calculate indices for individuals
n.obs <- daply(dat.unfold, .(ID), function(z) max(z$NUM.AFTER.DIAG) + 1)
df.new <- data.frame(ID = rep(unique(dat.unfold$ID), times = n.obs))
rle.new <- rle(df.new$ID)
ind.last <- cumsum(rle.new$lengths)
ind.first <- !duplicated(df.new$ID)
ind.first.w <- which(ind.first) 
ind.second <- ind.first.w + 1
ind2.to.last <- unlist(sapply(seq_along(ind.second), 
                function(z) ind.second[z]:ind.last[z]))

## insert time variables
df.new$time2 <- df.new$time1 <- NA
df.new$time1[ind.first] <- 0
df.new$time1[!ind.first] <- time1
df.new$time2[!ind.first] <- time2
df.new$time2[ind2.to.last - 1] <- time1
```

this gives me:

```
> df.new
    ID time1 time2
1  258     0  8401
2  258  8401 10425
3  284     0  9039
4  284  9039 10394
5  319     0  2039
6  319  2039  8827
7  319  8827  9466
8  319  9466 10333
9  322     0  1065
10 322  1065  2160
11 322  2160  3346
12 329     0  3287
13 329  3287  4657
14 329  4657 10456
```

This should work for the `STATUS` variable and the other variables in similar fashion.
When both steps are working separately, you just have to do one `rbind` step at the end.